# Does Mavericks Support MTP?

Tags: macos, file-transfer

Does Mavericks add support for [MTP devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) e.g. Android/Windows Phone?

I cannot find any mention of it.

Comment: What is a MTP device?

Comment: Assuming it's Media Transfer Protocol: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol I would expect no native support, though someone may know of a third-party solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mavericks does NOT support MTP natively.  You can use [Android File Transfer](http://www.android.com/filetransfer/) for MTP file system access or one of many other apps like [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com), or [AirDroid](http://www.airdroid.com) for file sharing that does not use MTP.

Comment: I haven't been able to get Android File Transfer to work. It just gives "cannot copy" errors. http://www.sync-mac.com/mtp-sync.html works for me, although it's unfortunately a paid app. Really sad Android has moved to this MTP protocol that makes copying to a Mac so much trouble.

Comment: @LanceNanek im pretty sure it is Apple that is causing the trouble rather than Android seeing as MTP and related protocols are fairly standard across manufacturers. Granted, Android could have kept USB mass storage available.

Comment: @AidenBell It's a disaster on Windows too. I have to rename a ZIP file to PNG to not get an error copying it over to the phone and then rename it back. On my Ubuntu Linux install it doesn't work either. If it is a standard, it certainly doesn't have any good implementations out there.

Comment: @LanceNanek - that's lame. I solved the issue by installing Fedora on my MBPr, which seems to "just work" much better than OSX once you sort out DPI issues :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's usually easier to use something like Droid NAS over wifi to browse your Android as a mounted drive. It's very slow, but comes with none of the shoddiness of AFT & you don't have to open a separate program for file management(?!).

Comment: Unfortunately Android File Transfer is only an option to... Android users. It is not available for other MTP protocol devices, such as Windows Phones.